# Linker errors when compiling against glib...?

Tags: compiling, linker, static-linking, glib

I'm having trouble compiling a simple, sample program against glib on Ubunutu.   I get these errors.  I can get it to compile but not link with the -c flag.  Which I believe means I have the glib headers installed, but it's not finding the shared object code.  See also the make file below.

```
$> make re
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -lglib-2.0       re.c   -o re
/tmp/ccxas1nI.o: In function `print_uppercase_words':
re.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `g_regex_new'
re.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `g_regex_match'
re.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `g_match_info_fetch'
re.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `g_print'
re.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `g_free'
re.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `g_match_info_next'
re.c:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `g_match_info_matches'
re.c:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `g_match_info_free'
re.c:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `g_regex_unref'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [re] Error 1
```

Makefile used:

```
# Need to installed libglib2.0-dev some system specific install that will
# provide a value for pkg-config
INCLUDES=$(shell pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0)
CC=gcc $(INCLUDES)
PROJECT=re

# Targets
full: clean compile

clean:
    rm $(PROJECT)

compile:
    $(CC) $(PROJECT).c -o $(PROJECT)
```

.c code being compiled:

```c
#include <glib.h>    

void print_upppercase_words(const gchar *string)
{
  /* Print all uppercase-only words. */

  GRegex *regex;
  GMatchInfo *match_info;

  regex = g_regex_new("[A-Z]+", 0, 0, NULL);
  g_regex_match(regex, string, 0, &match_info);

  while (g_match_info_matches(match_info))
    {
      gchar *word = g_match_info_fetch(match_info, 0);
      g_print("Found %s\n", word);
      g_free(word);
      g_match_info_next(match_info, NULL);
    }

  g_match_info_free(match_info);
  g_regex_unref(regex);
}

int main()
{
  gchar *string = "My body is a cage.  My mind is THE key.";

  print_uppercase_words(string);
}
```

Strangely, when I run `glib-config` it doesn't like that command -- though I don't know how to tell bash or make how to just use one over the other when it complains that `gdlib-config` is in these 2 packages.

```
$> glib-config
No command 'glib-config' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gdlib-config' from package 'libgd2-xpm-dev' (main)
 Command 'gdlib-config' from package 'libgd2-noxpm-dev' (main)
glib-config: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glib is not your problem.  This is:

```
re.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `print_uppercase_words'
```

What it's saying is you're calling a function `print_uppercase_words`, but it can't find it.

And there's a reason.  Look very closely.  There's a typo:

```
void print_upppercase_words(const gchar *string)
```

---

After you fix that, you might still have a problem because you are specifying the libraries before the modules that require those libraries.  In short, your command should be written

```
gcc -o re re.o -lglib-2.0
```

so that `-lglib-2.0` comes after `re.o`.

So I'd write your Makefile more like this:

```
re.o: re.c
        $(CC) -I<includes> -o $@ -c $^

re: re.o
        $(CC) $^ -l<libraries> -o $@
```

In fact, if you set the right variables, `make` will figure it all out for you automatically.

```
CFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
LDLIBS=$(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)
CC=gcc

re: re.o
```

Comment: Uh -- damn. I fixed the typo and I still have the errors found in what used to be print_upppercase_words (now with only 1 'p').  The reported error as an undefined reference to that function is now gone, but the glib linking errors are still present.

Comment: See my update.  My guess is that you need to put the `-lglib-2.0` *after* `re.c` or `re.o`.